# Does creating a vector graphic on a specific screen resolution affect the output quality on higher resolution screens?

Tags: vector, svg, resolution, image-quality

I'm creating my first game using the Unity game engine.

I plan to target `1920x1080px`; but my laptop resolution is `1366x768px`.

**If I create the vector image on my `1366x786px` screen, will the output be different or of less quality when it's displayed on a `1920x1080px` screen?**

Comment: No. Vector images are resolution independent--which is the primary benefit of using vector images.

Comment: But how about the height-width? wont that be effected  , it might get out of proportion.

Comment: You can stretch vectors but that will only affect the x/y ratios...not the quality of the output.

Comment: so to come to a conclusion , i'll be alright?

Comment: I can't say if you will be alright or not. :) But in terms of output quality, it doesn't matter what size or ratio you render a vector at--it will always be optimized for the particular output for that given device.

Comment: @DA01 ... should make that an answer since, well, there's not much else to add :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors are resolution independent as far as scaling goes so the quality of the graphics wont be an issue. What you will run into in your situation is content getting cut off when the field of view changes on different devices with different resolutions. The field of view is dependent on the the devices resolution or aspect ratio that the game is being rendered on.

Comment: It's true when increasing sizes, less true when reducing to small sizes (icons). See this very good explanation : http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/04/about-those-vector-icons.html. But in you case, this is not a problem.

Comment: @Drasill it's still true...the quality of the vector image doesn't change--however what does change is the quality that the device can render it at at small sizes, simply due to a lack of resolution. An important consideration, for sure.

Comment: From what I gather from the OP's question and comment about aspect, I think Derek's answer addresses what is really being asked here. "Yes" a full-scene render of a *pure vector* is actually of higher quality rendered on the 1920x1080 screen, by definition. **But** "yes" you will reduce the quality in a different sense if you merely set the width and height to 1920x1080. Since `1920/1366*786 != 1080`, it is obvious that you would be altering the aspect ratio. Either you live with it, or you crop it (which is why I think Derek mentions FOV)

Comment: Never used unity, but I suspect the solution would be to render to a surface which is the correct aspect ratio and use a viewport set to the screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks you guys , i have a basic understanding of what i'm dealing with now.